# Does the uniqueness of the best approximation element on a vector subspace always hold when it already exists?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be an inner product space. ($X$ may not be Hilbert nor finite-dimensional.)
Let $V$ be a vector subspace of $X$ ($V$ may be infinite-dimensional). Let $x\in X$.

Then we know that the best approximation of $x$ (i.e., a vector $y\in V$ satisfies $\|x-y\|=\inf_{z\in V}\|x-z\|$) may not exist. But suppose it exists, then is such vector unique?

I think the answer is yes, but I have just found a reference saying whether the "uniqueness" is hold is related to some kind of convexity, after he had just shown the existence in a particular circumstance (that is, $V$ is finite-dimensional).

My proof that existence implies uniqueness:
Let $y\in V$ satisfies $\|x-y\|=\inf_{z\in V}\|x-z\|$, then one can show that $x-y\in V^\perp$. If there is another $y'$ such that the $\|x-y'\|=\inf_{z\in V}\|x-z\|$, then again $x-y'\in V^\perp$. Since $X=V\oplus V^\perp$, $y=y'$. Is there any potential logical problem in the argument?

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier To show $X=V\oplus V^\perp$ (especially $X=V+V^\perp$), I think I should strengthen the hypothesis that *every* vector $x\in X$ has at least one best approximation (denoted as $y_x$). Then given any $\alpha\in V$, $\alpha=y_{\alpha}+(\alpha-y_{\alpha})$, where $(\alpha-y_{\alpha})\in V^\perp$.

Comment: Since it's a vector subspace, it's linear hence convex. Uniqueness should follow from convexity of $V$. If $V$ is also closed, then existence and uniqueness of best approximations is guaranteed.

Comment: @Zim Thank. I see. But the uniqueness (when existence hold) can be rigorously deduced without explicitly using the convexity of $V$ right?

Comment: You may not need to _explicitly_ use the convexity of $V$, but since there can be several best approximations to $x$ in a non-convex set, one does need to use convexity at least implicitly.

Comment: Yeah, @DanielFischer is right. You don't have to say the word "convex" in your proof, but I think it is kindof the idea behind it. A proof using linearity of $V$ would probably arise as a special case of a proof which used its convexity. You might also be interested in checking out the "Chebychev conjecture" which is related to your question https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~moors/James'thesis.pdf

Comment: @Zim Interesting. I'm going to study this paper. Thank you all.